# How to make Visual Studio 2010 render HTML with respect to carriage return

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010, master-pages

I have put this in master page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

In browser source I got this html which doesn't respect carriage return of masterpage between `<meta>` and `<title>`, so it is not formatted beautifully :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><meta charset="utf-8" /><title>
    Home Page
</title><link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

How to make Visual Studio 2010 render HTML with respect to carriage return

Comment: That is not Visual Studio's fault it is the Render method of the webcontrols involved in the System.Web namespace... I would say: don't bother....whitespace is not significant in html.

Comment: I know it's insignificant but for reading and documenting it's not :)